# Can't use created bean

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, autowired, bcrypt

I have a class in which I create a `@Bean` which is:

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

Then in other class I would like to use it but I can't beacuse it's said that the `Bean` hasn't been initialized.

Classes:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.inventory")
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("databaseUsersDetailsService")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

And here I would like to use it:

```
@Service
public class SessionService {

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder;
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    public SessionService(UserDetailsService userDetailsService, BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder, AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.encoder = encoder;
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }
```

In constructor it is said I can't use it due to `no beans BCryptPasswordEncoder was found`.

Does anyone has any idea what's wrong here? I am using `Spring Boot`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no `BCryptPasswordEncoder` instances within your Spring context. Actually, you've registered a bean with the `PasswordEncoder` type and you should inject exactly an object of that type.

It doesn't matter *what implementation of the `PasswordEncoder`* has been chosen, it does matter *the type you've declared* during bean registration.

Answer (score 1):

You are require to inject `BCryptPasswordEncoder` while there is no such type provided. You have 2 options

change to exact implementation as you are requiring one

```
@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

Or channge your inject requirement to more general type

```
@Autowired
public SessionService(UserDetailsService userDetailsService, PasswordEncoder encoder, AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
}
```

Both solutions will work.

Comment: injecting beans by child classes seems to be an awful idea to me

Comment: Its a common practice to inject implementation by interface, so I must disagree with you.

Comment: injecting implementation by interface is the right practice, but it isn't what you showed as the first option, right?